# is it possible to convert information from xml file to cpp

Tags: c++, xml

I'm writing here because I'm desperate and I really don't know what to do.
Long story short: In college, studying programming, been writing all my programs on C++ on Code Blocks. Final exam time: been studying for that shit for months. I go on our my designated computer and it turns out it doesnt have Code Blocks, only Visual studio. I write my code on visual studio, everything is working fine.
I turn in, what I presume is the .cpp file of the program (which should include the code) just the same as I would normally do in Code Blocks.

Turns out I've turned in an .xml file, which apparantly contains nothing of my code.

My question is: Is there any way to retrieve my code from that xml file? I really dont know what .xml files are so I have no clue.
Also what would you advice me do in this situation? Literally months of work have gone to waste in a single mistake, which is not even entirely my fault.

Sorry for the long rant, but had to vent out to someone.
Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you submitted the solution or project file which do not contain your code. The only way will be to retrieve it from the machine you wrote it on

Comment: ***Is there any way to retrieve my code from that xml file?*** No.

Comment: Your C++ code is there in the filesystem of the machine you wrote it on. You just submitted the wrong file(s). Go get the right one.

Comment: I future I recommend getting a free account somewhere like GitHub https://github.com/ Store your code there rather than somewhere it can get lost.

Comment: My guess is your OS has the extensions turned off ("hide extensions for known types" enabled). And you could not tell the difference between two files with the same name but different extensions..

Comment: Ahh I presumed the answers would be similar, but it is still painful to hear it from you guys. I guess if noone decided to delete the files from the computer, the code would still be there, but my teachers dont want to hear anything from it.
Apparantly what I have learned is notas important as following the bureaucracy step by step.
I guess if they want to listen, I can show that the files have not been modified since the day of the exam, but I highly doubt it
Sucks to be me, thank you anyways guys

Comment: Yeah, that is exaclty what happened. It appeared as regular cpp file to me.
In your honest opinion how much in the wrong am I?
I will repeat that this was the first time I had used Visual Studio and I had no idea of the extensions of the files. I jsut presumed they worked like the files in Code Blocks do.
They've been teaching us, coding on Code Blocks as well
How was I supposed to know what to send?

Comment: One of the first things I do when I setup a machine is to turn that setting off. Windows is not helping me by hiding the extension.

Comment: The extension for a cpp file should be the same as in Code::Blocks although in both cases the user can set this if they want when creating the file.

Comment: I have long considered Code::Blocks to be a punishment rather than an IDE, but even from my myopic and bigoted viewpoint this exceeds the crime. I feel for you, friend.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: **No.**

The .XML is the solution file that Visual Studio uses, which contains none of your code. If possible, I would speak with someone of importance at your testing location to gain access to that computer, and pull out the .cpp file in the folder where you saved it. If you didn’t specify where to save it, it’s most likely in documents/visual studio/.

**But!** You said you were in college, meaning these machines are most likely closely monitored along with the current Windows Install State being wiped clean and restored to the previous state it started on every time the computer is shut off, if that is the case, the you’re unfortunately out of luck.